# Pipeline metacharacter in variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, pipeline

In my bash script I need to check if logger binary exists. If so, I pipe the application output to it.

**Edit--------**
**|** It needs to be piping, the application should work permanently.
**---------------**

I tried to put the pipeline stuff to a variable and use it later. Something like:

```
if [ -e /usr/bin/logger ]; then
  OUT=| /usr/bin/logger 
fi

application  param1  2>&1   $OUT   >  /dev/null &
```

but it doesn't work, the output is not piped to the logger. If I put the pipeline stuff directly into the application startline, it works. **Unfortunately the real script becomes too complicated if I use command lines with and without logger stuff** in if/else statements - the reason is that I already have if/else there and adding new ones will double the number of cases.

Simple test application

```
TMP=| wc -m
echo aas bdsd vasd $TMP
```

gives

> $ ./test.sh
>   0
>   aas bdsd vasd

Seems that somehow command1 and command2 are executed separately.

I managed to solve the problem (in both test and real scripts) using `eval` and putting the conditional stuff in double quotes.

```
TMP="| wc -m"
eval echo aas bdsd vasd $TMP
```

> $ ./test.sh
>   14

It feels like a workaround. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: These are braces: `{}`, these are double *quotes*: `" "`. In regards to putting commands, pipes or redirection in variables, see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). And see my answer below.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Thank you for the note and for the link, it's very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use `if/else`:

```
if [ -e /usr/bin/logger ]
then
    application  param1  2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger >  /dev/null &
else
    application  param1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

**Edit:**

In the case of a complex construct, you should use a function:

```
foo () {
    if [ ... ]
    then
        do_something
    else
        something_else
    fi
    while [ ... ]
    do
        loop_stuff
    done
    etc.
}
```

Then your log/no log `if` stays simple:

```
if [ -e /usr/bin/logger ]
then
    foo  2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger >  /dev/null &
else
    foo > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I agree that for a simple case it's better to use if/else and put the logger stuff directly in the command lines. What about the cases when you have several if/else cases already and adding one more would double their total count? Maintaining them would become too hard.

Comment: @Dmitry: Just put the complex stuff in a function and keep the logger conditional simple. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw another option into the mix, you could move the pipe outside the variable:

```
if [ -e /usr/bin/logger ]; then
    logcmd=/usr/bin/logger
else
    logcmd=/bin/cat
fi

application param1 2>&1 | $logcmd >/dev/null &
```

This avoids having duplicate commands for the two cases (or having to wrap everything in functions, per Dennis' suggestion).  The disadvantage is that it's inefficient about how it handles the case where logger doesn't exist -- creating a `cat` process just to feed output to /dev/null is a complete waste.  But a `cat` process isn't *that* big a resource drain, so if it makes your code cleaner it might be worth the waste.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if [ -e /usr/bin/logger ]; then
  logger $(application  param1 2>&1)
fi
```

General rule: don't put commands inside variables and call it through the variable. Just run it directly off your script.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar code and specified the last line like this and it worked

```
application  param1  &2>1   ${OUT}   >  /dev/null
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any difference in neither of the mentioned examples when bracing the variable name

Answer (score 0):

While ghostdog74's answer is correct, there is certainly a way to make this work

```
if [ -e /usr/bin/logger ]; then
  OUT='| /usr/bin/logger'
fi

eval application param1 2>&1 $OUT > /dev/null
```

But I highly recommend that you think twice before using eval, and then don't use it.